# Multiple Panel Figures with Captions Grouped Together

Tags: floats

I have managed to make this:

[image]

but I'm trying to make this:

[image]

the difference being that the captions are grouped together in a minature format of the figure.

the code:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./figures/} }
\usepackage{float}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.33\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Image1BW.png} 
        \caption{}\label{fig:Image1BW}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.33\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Image1BWPhaseMaskOnly.png} 
        \caption{}\label{fig:Image1BWPhaseMaskOnly}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.33\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Image1BWSpatialAndPhaseMask.png} 
        \caption{}\label{fig:Image1BWSpatialAndPhaseMask}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.33\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Image3Colour.png} 
        \caption{}\label{fig:Image3Colour}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.33\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Image3ColourPhaseMaskOnly.png} 
        \caption{}\label{fig:Image3ColourPhaseMaskOnly}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.33\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Image3ColourPhaseAndSpatialMask.png} 
        \caption{}\label{fig:Image3ColourPhaseAndSpatialMask}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Development of code to encrypt image. (\subref{fig:Image1BW}) Image to be encrypted. (\subref{fig:Image1BWPhaseMaskOnly}) Encryption through convolution with phase mask. (\subref{fig:Image1BWSpatialAndPhaseMask}) Encryption through  multiplication and convolution with phase mask. (\subref{fig:Image3Colour})(\subref{fig:Image3ColourPhaseMaskOnly})(\subref{fig:Image3ColourPhaseAndSpatialMask}) Results of colour images through the same process.}
\end{figure}
```

EDIT: SUSSED IT NO SWEAT

```
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.33\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Image1BW.png}
            \caption{}\label{fig:Image1BW}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.33\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Image1BWPhaseMaskOnly.png} 
            \caption{}\label{fig:Image1BWPhaseMaskOnly}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.33\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Image1BWSpatialAndPhaseMask.png} 
            \caption{}\label{fig:Image1BWSpatialAndPhaseMask}
        \end{subfigure}
        
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.33\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Image3Colour.png} 
            \caption{}\label{fig:Image3Colour}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.33\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Image3ColourPhaseMaskOnly.png} 
            \caption{}\label{fig:Image3ColourPhaseMaskOnly}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.33\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Image3ColourPhaseAndSpatialMask.png} 
            \caption{}\label{fig:Image3ColourPhaseAndSpatialMask}
        \end{subfigure}
        \vfill
        \begin{matrix}
            \subref{fig:Image1BW} & \subref{fig:Image1BWPhaseMaskOnly} & \subref{fig:Image1BWSpatialAndPhaseMask}\\
            \subref{fig:Image3Colour} & \subref{fig:Image3ColourPhaseMaskOnly} & \subref{fig:Image3ColourPhaseAndSpatialMask}
        \end{matrix}
        \hfill  
        \caption{Development of code to encrypt image. (\subref{fig:Image1BW}) Image to be encrypted. (\subref{fig:Image1BWPhaseMaskOnly}) Encryption through convolution with phase mask. (\subref{fig:Image1BWSpatialAndPhaseMask}) Encryption through  multiplication and convolution with phase mask. (\subref{fig:Image3Colour})(\subref{fig:Image3ColourPhaseMaskOnly})(\subref{fig:Image3ColourPhaseAndSpatialMask}) Results of colour images through the same process.}\label{fig:Imaginary Encrypt}
    \end{figure}
```

[image]

Still isn't perfectly the same but getting there

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Could you edit your post to include your code? It'll tell us what package you used.

Comment: Updated to include the code and the packages used.

Comment: Consider accepting one of the provided answers.

Answer (score 2):

It is not entirely clear what exactly is your problem. A simple code, which reproduce showed desired result is:

```
\documentclass{book}    % used document class is unknown
\usepackage{geometry}   % page layout is unknown

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\graphicspath{ {./figures/} }

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{font=small, labelfont = bf}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} XXX @{}}
\includegraphics{example-image-a}   &   % {figures/Image1BW.png}
\includegraphics{example-image-b}   &   % {figures/Image1BWPhaseMaskOnly.png}
\includegraphics{example-image-c}   \\  % {figures/Image1BWSpatialAndPhaseMask.png}
    \addlinespace 
\includegraphics{example-image}     &   % {figures/Image3Colour.png}
\includegraphics{example-image}     &   % {figures/Image3ColourPhaseMaskOnly.png}
\includegraphics{example-image}         % {figures/Image3ColourPhaseAndSpatialMask.png}
    \end{tabularx}

\begin{minipage}{0.1\textwidth}\small
    \setlength\arraycolsep{3pt}
    $\begin{array}{ccc}
\mathbf{a}  & \mathbf{b}    &   \mathbf{c}  \\
\mathbf{d}  & \mathbf{e}    &   \mathbf{f}  
            \end{array}$
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}
    \caption{Development of code to encrypt image. 
(\textbf{a}) Image to be encrypted. 
(\textbf{b}) Encryption through convolution with phase mask. 
(\textbf{c}) Encryption through  multiplication and convolution with phase mask. 
(\textbf{a}) (\textbf{a}) (\textbf{a}) Results of colour images through the same process.}
    \label{fig:Imaginary Encrypt}
\end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the problem was i didnt know how to do it, thanks for this solution man

Answer (score 1):

Here's a janky solution, was much easier to make this on docs but here in latex land you don't have to manually reference things. Case in point, I can now automagically reference this figure and its subfigures FANTASTIC!

Here's the output:

[image: beauty]

Here's the code:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./figures/} }
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelfont= {color = white}, font = tiny}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont = bf}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.32\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Image1BW.png}
            \caption{}\label{fig:Image1BW}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.32\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Image1BWPhaseMaskOnly.png} 
            \caption{}\label{fig:Image1BWPhaseMaskOnly}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.32\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Image1BWSpatialAndPhaseMask.png} 
            \caption{}\label{fig:Image1BWSpatialAndPhaseMask}
        \end{subfigure}
        
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.32\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Image3Colour.png} 
            \caption{}\label{fig:Image3Colour}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.32\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Image3ColourPhaseMaskOnly.png} 
            \caption{}\label{fig:Image3ColourPhaseMaskOnly}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.32\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Image3ColourPhaseAndSpatialMask.png} 
            \caption{}\label{fig:Image3ColourPhaseAndSpatialMask}
        \end{subfigure}
        \vfill
        $\begin{minipage}{0.1\textwidth}
            $\begin{matrix}
                \textbf{\subref{fig:Image1BW}} & \textbf{\subref{fig:Image1BWPhaseMaskOnly}} & \textbf{\subref{fig:Image1BWSpatialAndPhaseMask}}\\
                \textbf{\subref{fig:Image3Colour}} & \textbf{\subref{fig:Image3ColourPhaseMaskOnly}} & \textbf{\subref{fig:Image3ColourPhaseAndSpatialMask}}
            \end{matrix}$
        \end{minipage}$
        \begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}
            \caption{Development of code to encrypt image. (\subref{fig:Image1BW}) Image to be encrypted. (\subref{fig:Image1BWPhaseMaskOnly}) Encryption through convolution with phase mask. (\subref{fig:Image1BWSpatialAndPhaseMask}) Encryption through  multiplication and convolution with phase mask. (\subref{fig:Image3Colour}) (\subref{fig:Image3ColourPhaseMaskOnly}) (\subref{fig:Image3ColourPhaseAndSpatialMask}) Results of colour images through the same process.\label{fig:Imaginary Encrypt}}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```